# bluetooth problem ubuntu

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth

I have a problem on Ubuntu 22.04 while using a bluetooth device. When I connect the bluetooth device to a computer with Windows and put on Spotify it sounds perfectly fine, but when the computer is running Ubuntu it sounds very cut and not fluid at all.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is your computer running?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe your computer is using HSP/HFP instead of A2DP, go into sound settings, then see what the Bluetooth device is set to use.

[image]